# MongoDB in container on Mac not binding ports

Tags: mac-osx, mongodb

I am trying to setup a local Mongo instance using Docker for development purposes.  I need to turn on authentication, and according to [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) it is possible.

The problem is, after I create the initial admin user (using those docs above), the next step is to connect "externally", which fails.  I would also like to be able to connect via thick client (I am using Robo 3T).

I created the docker container using:

```
docker run --name mongodb -p 0.0.0.0:27017:27017 -d mongo --auth
```

Then I created the admin user with:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo admin
> db.createUser({ user: 'root', pwd: '123456', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });
```

Then I tried to login externally using:

```
docker run -it --rm --link mongodb:mongo mongo mongo -u root -p 123456
```

to wit I get the error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-26T16:17:34.309+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-01-26T16:17:34.309+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I think I am misunderstanding something, but I am not sure what.

Comment: I am having the same problem. More specifically I can't seem to expose the MongoDB instance I have running in a Docker container on my Mac to external clients (e.g. Mongo Compass running on a PC). I have not enabled authentication, which is probably a good idea, but I would be happy just to connect from the remote computer. I can connect using Mongo Compass running locally on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the /data/db directory has the right permissions by running

> sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
>
> ## Enter your password

Comment: I don't have the /data/db volume mounted to my host, and I would hope that the official mongo container would have the permissions setup correctly for it's data folder.